# Splitting each element in a list of 128 elements which are in different sizes in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame which has 7 variables with 500 observations each. 
I got all the subsets of this dataset by using powerset function. Now, I have a list of 128 subsets, each has different sizes. I mean, I got 128 different datasets. 
How can I split these 128 subsets from the list?
Here is what I have so far;

```
#data generation part

x1=rnorm(n=500, m=2, sd=1);
x2=rbinom(n=500, 1 , 0.6);
y=rbinom(n=500, 1 , 0.7);
r1=rbinom(n=500, 1 , 0.65);
x1x1=x1*x1;
x1x2=x1*x2;
x1y=x1*y;
x2y=x2*y;
s=rbind(x1,x2,y,x1x1,x1x2,x1y,x2y);
sdata<-data.frame(t(s));

#getting subsets of 7 variables as a list

len = length(sdata)
l = vector(mode="list",length=2^len) ; l[[1]]=numeric()
counter = 1L
for(x in 1L:length(sdata)){
  for(subset in 1L:counter){
    counter=counter+1L
    id=rep(l[[counter]], nrow(l[[counter]]))
    l[[counter]] = data.frame(l[[subset]],sdata[x])
  }
}
```

So, "`l`" is a list contains 128 elements. Each element is a matrix with different sizes. I want them all splitted. I tried to add "id" vector for every element but i couldn't make it. If i could add id vectors for every element, i can split them by using ids.

Expected outcome is getting 128 different data frames (subsets) with different sizes. I want them to be seperate.

Do you have any suggestion or different idea for splitting this list?

Comment: Please describe the expected outcome.

Comment: Expected outcome is getting 128 different data frames (subsets) with different sizes. I want them to be seperate.

Comment: It isn't clear how you're getting your 128 different data frames in your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to ignore the trivial (null) subset, and consider that you want the other 127 combinations.

```
# This is your data
sdata <- matrix(1:(500*7), 500, 7)

# We generate all the possible combinations (127 cases)

sComb <- do.call(list, unlist(lapply(1:7, function(n) combn(1:7, n, simplify = F)), r = F))

# And then we create all the possible datasets

l <- lapply(sComb, function(i) sdata[,i])
```

Hope this helps

**Edit:**

If you want to conserve the names (and every element of the list as a matrix) change the last line to this one

```
l <- lapply(sComb, function(i){ x <- matrix(sdata[,i], nrow(sdata)); colnames(x) <- colnames(sdata)[i]; x })
```

Comment: Thank you so much @duran ! That is exactly what i seek. Just one more little detail. When i run the code, i can not see the variable names of the first 7 subsets (which are my orijinal data). All other subsets contain variable names except those 7. Do you have any solution for that?

Comment: Edited. Now conserves variable names.